# After added SLC6-OS repo to RHEL6, should I let it update 1200+ packages (400M)

Tags: rhel

I have RHEL6.4, and have added several repos to it to try and add some common tools, gcc for example.

It was recommended I add SLC6-OS and use that for installing tools like gcc, but when I do:

```
yum update
```

I get 1200+ updates, at over 400Meg.  Why and what is going on?  Should I?

RHEL 6.4

uname -r = 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64

```
[root@localhost yum.repos.d]# yum repolist
Loaded plugins: product-id, refresh-packagekit, replace, security, subscription-
              : manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
repo id         repo name                                                  status
epel            Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64             11,141
ius             IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64        232
ius-dev         IUS Community Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64 - D     25
pgdg93          PostgreSQL 9.3 6Server - x86_64                               256
rpmforge        RHEL 6Server - RPMforge.net - dag                           4,718
slc6-devtoolset Scientific Linux CERN 6 (SLC6) - Devtoolset addons            458
slc6-os         Scientific Linux CERN 6 (SLC6) base system packages         6,673
webtatic        Webtatic Repository 6Server - x86_64                          383
repolist: 23,886
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not subscribed to RedHat updates, therefore you will not be receiving any updates to any of the core packages.  Since you've now added the Scientific Linux repo, `yum` will notice that it now has access to packages that are far more up-to-date than your current installation and is trying to update them all.

If you continue, you'll end up with a Scientific Linux / RedHat hybrid system, which may become a real pig to manage.

As you're not subscribed to RedHat, you could consider migrating your system to CentOS.  There are risks involved (apparently) and details can be found on the CentOS [Migration HowTo](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/MigrationGuide).

There is also a [blog post](http://yourmacguy.wordpress.com/2013/08/27/rhel-to-sl/) on converting RHEL to Scientific Linux, but it's not official.